# Cross cutting concerns with Vertx

Tags: aop, vert.x

I need to handle cross cutting concerns through out my micro service built using vertx. Back in sometime we used spring AOP, but the tech stack is changed to Vertx and finding out a way if it's something even possible. Would like to take suggestions on all the possible options in this case.

Answer (score 0):

AOP is just another way to generate proxy classes. In Vert.x, you would usually achieve the same goal using Handlers and Context.

So let's say you'd like to have a logging around your endpoints. You can do it as follows:

```
Router filterRouter = Router.router(vertx);

filterRouter.get().handler((ctx)->{
    System.out.println("Before");
    ctx.next();
    System.out.println("After");
});
filterRouter.mountSubRouter("/", router);
```

If you don't want to proceed with the filter chain, you just won't invoke `ctx.next()` in your handler.

Comment: But i need to deal with those cross cutting not at endpoint level, but deeper in the code behind the endpoint. Let's say i am invoking a delegate/adapter or a db call as part of API call, configured/selected methods entry and exits, does the handlers and context solves the purpose?

Comment: Short answer is "yes". This was just a common example. Handlers are used all across Vert.x, and that's the way to handle (no pun intended) cross-cutting concerns.